# ItemsControl items do not render in ScrollViewer in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am trying to create a scrolling page within a Windows Phone app. This page has some static content followed by an ItemsControl of items.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">            
  <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Text="Static text line 1" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Another lineof static text" />

      <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"></ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Oddly, when I use this approach, the ItemsControl items do not render. However, if I move the ScrollViewer below the static text items, and place the ItemsControl within the ScrollViewer, my items render just fine.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like there has to be something small and insignificant that I'm overlooking. Thank you.

Comment: The first `TextBlock` and the `ItemsControl` are going to both be in the same grid row, which means one will overwrite the other, however I would think it was the `TextBlock` you wouldn't be able to see.

Comment: I missed the Grid.Row definition. Its there now.I agree with your assessment though. Still, my Items are not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line `<RowDefinition />` by `<RowDefinition Height="*" />`. The * means it will take all the available space.